# Clickhouses are stored independently by columns, how are their columns directly related?

Tags: sql, storage, clickhouse

clickhouses are stored independently by columns, how are they directly associated with each other? For example, when we query select a, b, c from table where a=? We search and query through a, how is the relationship between a and b, c related

I would like to know the specific query process, which involves multiple columns but only one condition, such as select a, b, c from table where a=?， thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data in each column file is sorted by the primary key - that's how ClickHouse keeps the rows "in sync". When you select a row where `a` equals a certain value, ClickHouse figures out the offset of which row that is based on the sort order, then opens the column files for `b` and `c` and retrieves the appropriate values.

It's why the primary key is an important design decision to make. ClickHouse builds an index on the primary key and could skip lots of rows if the data was sorted by column `a`.